# Offers page is loading slow because of multiple API's for fetching offers

Tags: php, api, performance, loading

We are building a platform where we need to fetch offers from different offer providers using their api's.
We are calling api's one by one from different offers provider, and this process is slowing down our offers page(where we are showing all offers). Is there any better way fetching offers from all different api's and it'll not impact the speed of loading offers.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is very wide :)
You should provide more information, i.e.

1. What's the SLA of the 3rd party APIs?
2. Do you need realtime data? You could cache your provider's responses.
3. Are you sure that you are not falling into a n+1 situation?
4. Do you have to authenticate each time with each 3rd party call?

Maybe you can copy/paste a silly diagram of your architecture, or just a bit of the code as an example.

Etc, etc...

About the n+1: Just Google "api n+1 problem" and you'll get tons of articles about it.
Here is one: https://www.sharpecho.com/microservices-and-the-n1-problem/